# Linear Transformation of $T : V \to V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear Transformation of $T : V \to V$  such that $T\circ T= T$ prove that $Ker(T) \cap Im(T) = \{ 0 \} $ ?!

I tried but i couldn't find the trick in this question

Also it's not a homework, it's a question from previous tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v \in Ker(T) \cap Im(T)$ , then $\exists w \in V$ such that $T(w)=v$.

Hence we have the following:

$$0=T(v)=T(T(w))=T(w)$$

which implies that $w \in Ker(T)$ (we used that $T^2=T$)

But then $v=T(w)=0_v$, hence the claim

Comment: Thanks, very smart answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $v\in Ker(T)\cap Im(T)$, then $T(v)=0$ and $v=T(w)$ for some $w\in V$, so $T(T(w))=(T\circ T)(w)=0$, but then $T(w)=0$ (due to $T\circ T=T$), i.e. $v=0$.

Comment: I really like how we have the same notation :)

Answer (score 2):

Since $T^2=T$ the transformation $T$ is the solution of polynomial $x^2-x=0$. Hence the possible eigenvalues are $\{0,1\}$. In particular since $x^2-x=0$ is the minimal polynomial, hence $T$ is diagonalizable. The eigenspaces of such endomorphism are $\text{Ker}T$ and $\text{Im}T$, hence
$Ker(T) \cap Im(T) = \{ 0 \} $.